# Why mmma generates additional demo apps and test apps in /system/app?

Tags: android-source

I am building AOSP-angler 8.0 rom on HUAWEI nexus6P.

A clean build `make` works fine.

When I run `mmma framework/base` to rebuild the framework module, it always generates some additional apps in folder out/target/product/angler/system/app/.

[Screenshot to this folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R6nV.png)

As you can see, all apps are sorted in modified time. The selected ones are generated during `mmma`.

I have to delete these apps before `make snod` to wrap a system image every time. Otherwise they all will get installed in the device.

Why is this? I wonder if there is a "build rule" which `mmma` follows and how can I change the build script to get a "clean" `mmma`?

Answer (score 0):

`mmma` will ignore the `PRODUCT_PACKAGES +=` statement in makefile and build all modules under the path.